# Help Needed: I removed mysql db access permissions for root user. How can I gain access again?

Tags: mysql, permissions, root

I accidentally removed access permissions of database mysql to the root user.

I'm now not able to create new databases, set permissions, etc.

What can I do to gain access again?

Answer (score 3):

This will result in interruption of service.  Update the init file to contain the commands necessary to re-create the root user.  The procedure is documented here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html